# remove domain prefix for sharepoint 2013 login

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-farm

I have Sharepoint 2013 farm which has a  two way trust relationship with another domain.

The user is forced to  type the domainname\user to login .

IS there a way that the user does not need to enter the domain name  in Internet explorer and just enters the User name

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is not unique to your domain trust configuration, it's this way with traditional domain deployments as well. Typically when you see the logon prompt it will show you the domain you are trying to logon to.  If this is already the correct domain you don't have to prefix (or use UPN).  If this is not the correct domain then you must specify it as part of the logon process.

If the users use a domain account to logon on to their windows machines you can add the URL to their intranet zone (or any zone if you configure it to allow automatic logon). This does not remove the domain requirement but will pass it silently in the background so the users doesn't need to see the logon prompt.

The other method is to enable forms based authentication.  This will allow you to control the authentication inputs - however you can't use the automatic logon functionality as stated above.

For non-windows based machines like MAC you can configure password helper like KeyChain to store and forward the credentials.  The password vault in windows would work in a similar fashion.

Comment: In IIS checking enabled kernel mode authentication under the windows authenciation section would this have an impact

Comment: SharePoint does not support kernel mode authentication - and no.  The problem is client side not in IIS.  You are sending over the domain information whether you specify it or not.  If you send over the wrong information (such as local computer vs. domain) you wont' get authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking two solution for this scenario.

1. Implement the [ADFS authentication,](https://sharepointobservations.wordpress.com/2013/08/19/sharepoint-2013-how-to-install-and-configure-adfs-2-0/) this will by pass the domain prefix.
2. other thought is configure the [Basic Authentication](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg576953.aspx) for the web app.But one thing keep in mind,

> Basic authentication enables a web browser to provide credentials when
>   the browser makes a request during an HTTP transaction. Because user
>   credentials are not encrypted for network transmission but are sent
>   over the network in plaintext, we do not recommend that you use basic
>   authentication over an unsecured HTTP connection. To use basic
>   authentication, you should enable Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)
>   encryption for the web site; otherwise, the credentials can be
>   intercepted by a malicious user.

Comment: I am using Windows authentication  with an SSL would this cause any issues if I enable basic authentication.